# Renaming elements of a list

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a series of files I would like to read in a series of csv's and then make individual tibbles from the files created.  So currently I can read the files all in:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read_csv)
```

Which creates a list of six tbl's.  I thought about doing this as:

```
temp_list <- as.list(gsub("[[\\.csv]","",(temp)))
```

Which will give the list of the read csv file names with the csv removed from the end.  I thought about trying this but certainly will not work

```
names(myfiles) <- names(temp_list)
```

I can name them individually but would rather have a cleaner/single function would be best that could generate the results.

```
filea <- myfiles[[1]]
fileb <- myfiles[[2]]
filec <- myfiles[[3]]
filed <- myfiles[[4]]
filee <- myfiles[[5]]
filef <- myfiles[[6]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `names(myfiles) <- gsub("...` You just need to provide a vector with names of the same length and order of the elements in your list.

Comment: Maybe `map(temp, read_csv) %>% set_names(tools::file_path_sans_ext(temp)) %>% list2env(.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: This is perfect!  I tweaked it just slightly here to be:    
    purrr::map(temp,read_csv) %>% 
    set_names(tools::file_path_sans_ext(temp)) %>% list2env(.GlobalEnv)

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to create individual tibbles (no more lapply, your workspace becomes a mess etc), what's wrong with keeping them in a list ?

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to be able to create the tibbles to see if that helps to view the different tables to get a better understanding of their attributes.  However, for my next iteration I might end up keeping the list view.

Comment: Many users seem to be more comfortable analysing a table that exists "as itself" in the workspace, I believe it has to do with the cognitive load, you feel that you've created a cleaner space, at least I remember feeling this way. Somewhat shorter syntax for a few operations is another reason, but I believe you'll find that this is misguided, anything you can do with a variable can be done with a list element and when you destroy existing structure in your data it often comes to back to haunt you later :).

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I'll have to explore that as I imagine this can certainly bring unintended downstream consequences down the road :).